# numpy two arrays satisfy different condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing

The specific question is I have an binary image. Now I would like to get the indices of pixels such that they fall into a specific area. So I first take `nonzeroPixel = nonzero(img)` and get their x and y value(i.e coordinate) by `Py=np.array(nonzeroPixel[0])` and `Px=np.array(nonzeroPixel[1])`. 
Say the rectangle area I expect them to fall into is `x in (10,20)` and `y in (30,40)`
My question is how to get the indices of pixels falling in this rectangle area? Which means `10<Px<20` && `30<Py<40`.

I tried `np.where((Py >= 30) & (Py < 40) & (Px >= 10) &  (Px < 20))` but I think it only works for one array?

Here is a possible solution but I don't know what function of numpy it is using.

```
good_pixel_index = ((Py > 30) & (Py < 40) & (Px > 10) &  (Px < 20)).nonzero()[0]
```

Any thoughts will be appreciated

Comment: No, you don't want to use `where` here. You want to take a _slice_ of the array using indices. That will define the "scope" or portion of the array under consideration

Comment: `np.nonzero(img)` returns a tuple of arrays.  `nonzeroPixel[0]` is already an array.  `np.where` with one argument (your condition) is the same as `np.nonzero` (and the `nonzero()` method).

Comment: @hpaulj thank you and your clear answer! BTW I want to know is expression `(condition).nonzero()[0]` kind of python thing? I am new to this sorry.

Comment: `(condition)` is a numpy array.  `.nonzero()` is a method of the array.  `np.nonzero(condition)` is the equivalent function form.  `[0]` is indexing, selecting the first item from the tuple produced by `nonzero`.  Taken piece by piece it is all python (and numpy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a concrete example:

```
In [168]: img = np.random.randint(0,2,(10,10))                                  
In [169]: img                                                                   
Out[169]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
In [170]: idx = np.nonzero(img)                                                 
In [171]: idx                                                                   
Out[171]: 
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3,
        3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
        7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 1, 4, 6,
        7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 3, 7, 9, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 0, 1, 3, 5, 6,
        7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7]))
In [172]: jdx = np.nonzero((idx[0]>=3)&(idx[0]<=8)&(idx[1]>4)&(idx[1]<9))       
In [173]: jdx                                                                   
Out[173]: (array([21, 22, 26, 27, 29, 35, 36, 37, 42, 43, 44, 45, 51, 52, 53]),)
In [174]: idx1 = (idx[0][jdx],idx[1][jdx])                                      
In [175]: idx1                                                                  
Out[175]: 
(array([3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8]),
 array([6, 7, 5, 8, 7, 5, 6, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 7, 8]))
In [176]: img[idx1]                                                             
Out[176]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

And to better visualize which points we selected:

```
In [177]: img[idx1] = 2                                                         
In [178]: img                                                                   
Out[178]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]])

In [180]: img[3:9, 5:9]                                                         
Out[180]: 
array([[0, 2, 2, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 2, 0],
       [2, 2, 0, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 0, 2, 2]])

In [182]: np.argwhere(img[3:9, 5:9])   # transpose of `nonzero`                                            
Out[182]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       ...
       [5, 2],
       [5, 3]])
```

Applying the slicing offset as @roganjosh suggests, recreates the `idx1` arrays:

```
In [183]: np.argwhere(img[3:9, 5:9])+[3,5]                                      
Out[183]: 
array([[3, 6],
       [3, 7],
       [4, 5],
       [4, 8],
       [5, 7],
       [6, 5],
       [6, 6],
       [6, 8],
       [7, 5],
       [7, 6],
       [7, 7],
       [7, 8],
       [8, 5],
       [8, 7],
       [8, 8]])
```

I don't think it matters which route you take.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with slices, not `np.where`.

```
import numpy as np

# Make some fake 100x100 data
arr = np.random.randint(0, 2, 10000).reshape(100, 100)

# Select the correct slice (rows, columns)
print(arr[30:40, 10:20])

# Find the indices of the slice that aren't zero
ones = arr[30:40, 10:20].nonzero()

# Bump up the indices by the starting value of the slice
x_coords = ones[0] + 30
y_coords = ones[1] + 10
```